# Difference between hosting a Web API and hosting a website

Tags: api, networking, server, web-hosting

From what I've gathered, hosting a website on a server is allocating space for the files of your website whereas hosting an API is when the server continuously runs your API to receieve incoming web requests. Is it true that when hosting a website, the server is not running anything? Or is it also continuously running the website waiting for calls.

Answer (score 1):

When you request a website, it makes a call through the network to a server machine that runs an application called a web server, for example Apache HTTP Server. Without that application, it would be unable to respond to your HTTP calls with web pages.

Web pages are just documents and resources, so they are not able to respond by themselves. An API, on the other hand, is usually a separate standalone application that can run on a different machine, and that is often called by web pages.

So the answer is no: the server has to run something even for a static website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For clarification, so a server machine has to CONTINUOUSLY run the web server application for the website to be hosted, right? Likewise for an API, a machine has to CONTINUOUSLY run the API application for web apps to request to it, right? Sorry if these are really dumb questions, am very new to networking.

Comment: @Arararagi Yes, it has to run it continuously, and same with the API. In particular, both can be stopped or restarted (e.g. for an upgrade), and that means downtime for the web app.

Answer (score -1):

You need a server to "serve" your web-page. It does not matter if is a static page or a dynamic page (html or php). If you have a html page the server will read and sent it to the user(No processing done), if you have a dynamic page like php then the server will process the php code and generate a result usually an HTML page that its serve to the client.

If you have an API is the same approach as the dynamic page, you send parameters, server process them and then give you a result. In the case of an API it may require authentication and the result can be in HTML, XML, JSON for example.